# openssl: how to read a .crt file..?

Tags: c, certificate, openssl, x509, readfile

I want to read the `certifi.crt` file using OpenSSL API (not in commands).  I have no idea how to do that.  If any one knows, please help me. Thank you.

If you give example code that will be very helpful.

Comment: If you can figure out how to do it with the command-line tools, then you have all the example code you need, since it's "Open" SSL after all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the ".crt" extension refers to a PEM text file (begins with -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- followed by base64), then get started in the OpenSSL docs [here](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/pem.html).

Here is some code to get you started (link with ssl, e.g. g++ a.c -lssl):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <openssl/x509.h>
#include <openssl/pem.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    FILE* f = fopen("certifi.crt", "r");
    if (f != NULL)
    {
        X509* x509 = PEM_read_X509(f, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        if (x509 != NULL)
        {
            char* p = X509_NAME_oneline(X509_get_issuer_name(x509), 0, 0);
            if (p)
            {
                printf("NAME: %s\n", p);
                OPENSSL_free(p);
            }
            X509_free(x509);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```